# Is there a keyboard shortcut to return to previous position?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Is there a keyboard shortcut to return to previous position?

The <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> seems to be back to last *"editing position"*, rather than the last position of the cursor

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

Found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20191115212516/https://www.computerhope.com/tips/tip123.htm

Comment: Doesn't work for me in MS Word 2013 on Win 10

Comment: Works for Word 2016.
(Mentioned so people would know).

Comment: I have "Microsoft Professional Plus 2010". Word reports its version as 14.0.6129.5000 (32-bit). Running on Win7. This answer works for me.

Comment: Works on Microsoft Word 2016 MSO 64-bit.

Comment: What is the *name* of this command? (so that it can be added to the toolbar). It is not "GoBack", which goes to previous edit.

Comment: @Dmitri: Ctrl+Alt+Z/Shift+F5 is "GoBack" and Alt+Left is "WebGoBack".

Comment: Doesn't work for me (Word 2016, Win 10)

Comment: @Cameron Where are those short names used? I was trying to use them to add them to the Quick Access toolbar

Comment: @golimar: Think I found them by recording a macro, so, VBA. For the Quick Access toolbar, `WebGoBack` seems to be called just "Back", and `GoBack` seems to be "Previous Edit".

Answer (score 15):

You can use the keyboard shortcut for that command: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>.

Comment: Worked for me in MS Word 2013 on Win 10

Comment: Works better than the accepted answer, Also easier to use, as it does not require 3 key presses.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me when moving between bookmarks on Office 365.

Comment: perfect answer..worked for me